# OS X 10.8: redirecting locally initiated ssh connections to localhost:22

Tags: routing, nat, apple, pf, ipfw

I need to hack the OS X pf to redirect all ssh connections from an user to this machine. I want, when doing

```
$ ssh google.com
```

to get the same results as with

```
$ ssh localhost
```

ie a connection to my locally running sshd.

Under a recent Linux, this would simply be:

```
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m owner --uid-owner theuser -j REDIRECT
```

Under OS X 10.8, there appear to be 2 methods - ipfw and pf. Neither works.
Ipfw:

```
# ipfw flush
# ipfw add 50 fwd 127.0.0.1,22 tcp from any to any 22 uid theuser
```

If I drop the `uid theuser` part, the redirect works, minus the user thingie. If I leave the `uid` directive there, the network stack dies and the system shortly becomes unusable; no more `ipfw`, no more `ps`, no more `kill`.

According to the man pages, ipfw is deprecated, so packet filter should be used instead:

```
# sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

Then I added

```
anchor "910.Custom/*"
load anchor "910.Custom" from "/etc/pf.anchors/910.Custom"
```

in `/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple` and

```
rdr on en1 proto TCP from any to any port 22 -> 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

in `/etc/pf.anchors/910.Custom` (notice how I'm not mentioning anything about a user here, since the pf docs don't list such an option for rdr rules).

After I run `# pfctl -ef /etc/pf.anchors/com.apple` nothing happens. If I add garbage to `/etc/pf.anchors/910.Custom` or even if I dare add `user theuser` after the `rdr` rule, the firewall fitfully complains of the bad syntax.

Can the OS X kernel even perform NAT routing anymore, or did Apple yank out that functionality? If it can, am I missing anything?

LE. fixed `iptables` syntax

Comment: I'd love to know why you want to do this instead of just disabling SSH.

Comment: This is not the real thing I need to do. I took port 22 TCP just as a simplified, easy to test in other places, example.

Comment: I'm actually constructing an RTMP proxy. Here you go, no nonesense. If it makes sense now, eagerly waiting for the solution.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with PF as well. However, `rdr` only accepts incoming packets. Thus, you have to first route those packets to lo0, then add a `rdr`-rule there (which will catch them as they will be routed in from "somewhere") to send them to your local SSH-server.

The order is necessarily: `rdr` stuff, then filter stuff (like pass), but chronologically the 2nd rule will hit first (on `$Out`), which will then activate the first rule (on `lo0`).

```
# Output interface
Out = en0

# A macro to shorten rules below
Packets = "proto tcp from" $Out "to any port 22"

# Rule 1: Redirect those connections _after_ they were routed to lo0 below
rdr pass log on lo0 $Packets -> 127.0.0.1

# Rule 2: Route _first_ new IPv4 TCP connections leaving $Out to lo0
pass out on $Out route-to lo0 inet $Packets
```

Comment: This way does not work for ppp0. Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly does it not work? After applying this config, does ssh still reach the destination on the internet, or do the packets just seem to get lost?

Comment: Traffic to the proxy cannot be reached.

Comment: @Dan From the **pf.conf(5)** man page, "Macros are not expanded inside quotes". I replaced `$Out` inside of the `$Packets` assignment and pfctl stopped complaining about syntax errors.

Comment: @Dan hey man, can you help me out on my question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223944/pf-port-forwarding-on-os-x-yosemite-to-avoid-block)? thanks!

Comment: May I enquire as to why the `Out` and `Packets` macros are used? Is it a stylistic thing or would using `en0` etc change the processing somehow?

Comment: Well, first of all this ruleset simply won't load due to syntax errors.