# Enabling pf for transparent proxy on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: mac-osx, proxy, pf

I'm doing some usability testing of a web application and am attempting to debug and record some SSL sessions using `mitmproxy` as a transparent proxy and for some reason `pf` under Mac OS X Mountain Lion isn't setting up the transparent redirects.

First, I enable forwarding:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

Next, I create a simple `pf.conf` file with a single line on it:

```
rdr on {en1, en0} inet proto tcp to any port {80, 443} -> 192.168.1.40 port 3128
```

Where the 192.168.1.40 is the remote host that is currently running `mitmproxy` and `en1` and `en2` are the main outgoing interfaces on the Mac.

Finally, I start up `pf` with the following commands:

```
sudo pfctl -vf pf.conf
sudo pfctl -e
```

However, nothing happens. When I list the currently running rules for `pf` with `pfctl -sr` it doesn't show anything.

I've confirmed that `pf` can work on the machine by giving it a dummy rule which blocks all outbound access to port 80 and that works.

Any hints about what else I need to do to enable `pf` to redirect web traffic to a transparent proxy on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Comment: I had the same issue. Have a look at the answer written by Dan on this ServerFault question: http://serverfault.com/questions/421261/os-x-10-8-redirecting-locally-initiated-ssh-connections-to-localhost22

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `net.inet.ip.scopedroute=0`? From http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/1/6/osx-wifi-proxy/:

> Now currently if you finish that above setup you will notice that
>   nothing actually works. The cause for this is a Bug in the OS X kernel
>   that requires flipping the net.inet.ip.scopedroute flag to 0. I am not
>   entirely sure what it does, but the internet reports that it breaks
>   network sharing through the user preferences. In any case it fixes
>   ipfw based forwarding so you can flip it with sysctl:
>
> `$ sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.scopedroute=0`
>
> Unfortunately in OS X Lion this flag can actually not be flipped from
>   userspace so you need to set it as boot parameter and then restart
>   your computer. You can do this by editing the
>   /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist file
>   (continued...)