# How to divert all OUTBOUND tcp traffic on port 1935 to localhost?

Tags: mac-osx, pf

Mac OS X 10.10.3.

I'm trying to use rtmpsrv. In order to do that, I have to redirect all outgoing tcp traffic on port 1935 to localhost. I tried:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1

echo 'rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 1935 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1935' | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

which seemed to have no effect.

I tried to follow the answer here:
[OS X 10.8: redirecting locally initiated ssh connections to localhost:22](https://serverfault.com/questions/421261/os-x-10-8-redirecting-locally-initiated-ssh-connections-to-localhost22)
which gave me syntax error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.